# Definition of rational equivalence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles, projective-varieties

In the book "C. Voisin. Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry. Volume II. Cambridge studies in advanced mathematics 76 (2002)" page 247, definition 9.4,  says:

Definition 9.4.
The group ${Z_k(X)}_{\mathrm{rat}}$ of cycles rationally equivalent to $0$ is a subgroup of $Z_k(X)$ generated by the cycles of the form
\begin{equation*}
    \tau_* \operatorname{div}(\phi), \dim(W)=k, \phi\in R(W)^*
\end{equation*} where,   $\tau:\tilde{W}\rightarrow W\subset X$ is the normalization of a closed $(k+1)$-dimensional subvariety of $X$.

In this definition, I think there is a typo, it should say $\dim(W)=k+1$ instead of $\dim(W)=k$. Am I right or I am missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is a typo: indeed the text says that $W$ is $(k+1)$-dimensional.

Comment: Dear @abx Also it should say $\phi\in R(\tilde{W})^*$, right?

Comment: $R(\tilde{W} )=R(W)$.